# Include nested objects/relations with filter in Rails JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Can anyone offer some advice as to what the "best" way to include nested objects/relations in a JSON response that you want to filter?

In the simple example below, say the model `Comment` has a soft delete flag `is_deleted = true`, I want to only include comments that have `is_deleted = false`. What's the best way to accomplish this?

```
posts = Post.all
render json: posts.to_json(:include => [:comments])
```

Answer (score 1):

I could come up with a simple solution. In `Post`, you can scope the deleted comments out from the results, like this:

```
has_many :comments, -> { is_deleted: false }
```

This will return only those comments, which are not deleted. And then, your existing JSON code will work fine.

**Edit 1:**

This solution is as per our discussion in comments.

Create a convenience method in `Post`. This will return all the comments which are not deleted.

```
def visible_comments
  comments.where(is_deleted: false)
end
```

Then, you can change your render method as follows:

```
render json: posts.to_json(:include => [:visible_comments])
```

This will call the `visible_comments` method of `Post` and will include the results returned by that method only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try this, but we also don't want that scope to apply all the time since we do display comments that have been deleted to our "admins".

Comment: In that case, you can create a custom scope e.g. `scope :visible_comments, -> { comments.where(is_deleted: false) }`, and include this scope in your JSON rendering.

Comment: Do you know what the syntax is for including a custom scope?

Comment: @TimS -- My bad! You don't need to create a custom scope. A convenience method will do the trick. See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked, - thanks a ton! I don't suppose there's a way to rename or alias the convenience method is there? I couldn't find anything, but something like `:include => [:visible_comments as :comments]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your modal

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  

   def as_json(_options = {})
    super only: [:id, :title],
          include: {
            comments: {
              only: [:id, :comment_fieds]
            }
   end
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where is_deleted: false }
end
```

You can add comments and post field in only: [.....] that you want to include in response

```
posts = Post.all
render json: posts
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try this, but we also don't want that scope to apply all the time since we do display comments that have been deleted to our "admins".